# If I set $_SESSION variables in my PHP API Script, are they automatically stored by AFNetworking 2

Tags: php, session, cookies, afnetworking-2

I need help with AFNetworking and setting data for users. I have an iOS app that a User will use to access data. I have used AFNetworking 2.2 to successfully login, but I would like to use data $_SESSION data from the PHP Login script to populate queries on other views.

For example if Joe Bloggs logs into the app, I am setting $_SESSION variables from the SQL query as:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
```

What I would like to do is have those variables stored when I return the data to my app so that I can use those values to POST it back to another end point and query related user data from the database.

From what I have read, AFNetworking will automatically save cookies, but is the SESSION data stored as well? if not, how would I store these values? Alternatively, if these values cannot be stored, can I use the data from the cookies to retrieve the values in the $_SESSION variables once return to the next end point?

SOrry I am a little lost. I hope this makes sense.

---

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('DbConnector.php');

$connector = new DbConnector();

$username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'],ENT_QUOTES);
$password=md5($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT id, username, password, name FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND enabled = '1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //compare the password
    if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)==0)
    {

        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];       
        $userSession = json_encode ($_SESSION['name']['user']['id']);

        echo '{"success":1}';

        //echo '{"custid":$custid, "username":"$username", "name":"$name"}';
 } else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';


}
}else {    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}'; 

}

?>
```

Comment: sidenote, `$_SESSION` is all caps

Comment: Yeh sorry that was a typo lol. its in the script as all caps

Comment: and you have `session_start();` at the top of your script, before any other output, yes?

Comment: Yes, I have edited question to show entire PHP login script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after a week trying to get this working properly, I found that I simply had to set the $_SESSION variables, and then on success, these must become accessible based on info set in the header.

Future queries can be populated with $_SESSION variables as ing as you have correctly started the session in all PHP scripts that you plan to use.

I did get some errors initially that came because of the fact that I was trying to write JSON to the header (check the $userSession variable in my script) once I commented the offending line out, it works great!!